# How to resolve dependency in android library for depended modules

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'm working on an Android SDK that is created from 5 modules. that each of these below modules is an android library:

-view

-IO

-Domain

-Base

-Util

And `view` module has imported all the modules into it's Gradle, like below:

```
   /*-----------------------/IO Module\-------------------*/
    implementation project(path: ':io')

    /*-----------------------/Base Module\-------------------*/
    implementation project(path: ':base')

    /*-----------------------/Domain Module\-------------------*/
    implementation project(path: ':domain')

    /*-----------------------/Util Module\-------------------*/
    implementation project(path: ':util')
```

But when I wan to import my library into an application, by adding the dependency of `view` module, classes of the other modules will not be recognized in the application and I have to import all the modules into my application Gradle file. like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    /*-----------------------/view Module\-------------------*/
    implementation project(path: ':view')

    /*-----------------------/Domain Module\-------------------*/
    implementation project(path: ':domain')


    /*-----------------------/Base Module\-------------------*/
    implementation project(path: ':base')

    /*-----------------------/Util Module\-------------------*/
    compile project(path: ':util')

}
```

Comment: You not need to reimport module again if they already imported in ":view" module

Comment: can you post gradle of any one of your module like base or domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `api` instead of `implementation` in view `build.gradle` file. `api` is the same as deprecated `compile` option but `implementation` provide classes only to your module but not to modules that depend on it.